# Reinforcement learning for a word game

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, dqn

Let's imagine a simple word game where there is a grid of letters. The agent starts at a letter and moves to a neighboring letter, continuing in this fashion to form a word. For instance in this grid we can make the word STACK:

A  S  T

R  A  C

L  K  H

So the environment is the board, the current word, and current location. The actions are 8 moves and submit action.
If the submitted word is a valid English word, we score based on letter values and length. In other cases (invalid moves, invalid word etc.) negative reward.

I attempted DQN with a basic 2 hidden layer NN, based on [this solution](https://github.com/udacity/deep-reinforcement-learning/tree/master/dqn/solution). The agent initially has high negative score due to illegal moves and non-dictionary words. Even though the score improves as the agent learns to stay within game bounds and all, I find that the agent has difficulty learning the words in the vocabulary. So the score never even becomes positive. First of all the English vocabulary is large (tens of thousands of words) and during the game play the agent never even encounters most of the words, as it is highly unlikely for it to happen.

I tried restricting the possible letters to a few (the letters E T A I N) and in this case the agent learned to make super simple 3 letter words such as tat, tit etc. and make to a positive score.

I want to somehow have an agent already knowing the English dictionary. How can I incorporate the dictionary into the NN or the agent?

Alternatively, could there be a training procedure to have the agent learn the English dictionary?